# Crash when storing NSMutableArray with NSFilemanager

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsfilemanager

So I#m trying to save an array to a file. This should be done in the following code but by calling the  `addProjectsObject` method, the program crashes withe the following error code:

```
***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteData count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7eeb800'**
```

I'post the code that i think is relevant for the Problem, also i need to mention that there is another file stored in the same *filePath*, and it works perfectly. It occurred to me that the path might be the problem, but since both files have different names that shouldn't be the problem right?

```
-(void) addProjectsObject:(NSString *)newProject{

    projects = [self getProjectsFromDisk];
    [projects addObject:newProject];
    [self saveProjectsToDisk];

}   



-(NSMutableArray *) getProjectsFromDisk{

    NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fileName =  @"projects";
    NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:nil attributes:nil];}

    NSMutableArray* temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath]]; 

    return temp;

}

-(void) saveProjectsToDisk {

    NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fileName =  @"projects";
    NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:nil attributes:nil];}


    [projects writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];

}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging exactly at which point application is crashing?

Comment: as The Saad says, the problem seems to be in this line: NSMutableArray* temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath]];

i seem to miss something about the datatypes but i have absolutely no idea what it might be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSData` is **NOT** `NSArray`.

`[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:]` expects an instance of NSArray.
`[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath]` returns an instance of NSData.
Those two won't work together.

If `projects` is an `NSMutableArray` simply use this:

```
NSMutableArray* temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath];
```

The rest of the code can be stripped down too. There is no need to check if a file exist, or even create a file just to overwrite it two lines later.

This will work too:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)projectsFromDisk {
    NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fileName =  @"projects";
    NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSMutableArray* temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath];
    if (!temp) {
        // if file can't be read (does not exist, or invalid format) create an empty array
        temp = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return temp;
}

- (void)saveProjectsToDisk {
    NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fileName =  @"projects";
    NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [projects writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot and I see much clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

this is cz you are assigning inappropriate pointer, you assigned an NSConcreteData object pointer to NSMutablearray and tried to call some array method due to which this occured

Comment: so whats the correct procedure? do i have to somehow convert die Data?

Comment: [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray] try this it will return an array

Comment: hahaha. i'm not a sir, jst a developer like u. :) ask anythng anytime. skype: the_saad1